# Using Boolean operators

Tags: logic

This works fine

```
if ((a >= 40 && a <= 50) || (a >= 60 && a <= 80))
// do something
```

How do I do the reverse of it?

```
if ((a < 40 && a > 50) || (a < 60 && a > 80))
// do something
```

The code does not work as expected. I want something like *if not (condition)*

Comment: How can a number be less than 40 AND greater than 50 at the same time?

Comment: "The code does not work as expected." -- 
What did you really expect when you're asking for a number that is both less than 40 and greater than 50 at the same time?

Comment: might be working in a modulo space :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to look at [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
1. !((a >= 40 && a <= 50) || (a >= 60 && a <= 80))

2. (!(a >= 40 && a <= 50) && !(a >= 60 && a <= 80))

3. ((!(a >= 40) || !(a <= 50)) && (!(a >= 60) || !(a <= 80))

4. ((a < 40 || a > 50) && (a < 60 || a > 80))


or in other words: (a < 40 || (50 < a && a < 60) || 80 < a)
```

Comment: +1. Several examples that all demonstrate a possible solution complete with a reference on where to get more information.

Comment: Logically correct, but the result is hard to read and it inhibits short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: also I managed to combine two steps into one. now that's fixed

Comment: Much better than my quick fix

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((a < 40 || a > 50) && (a < 60 || a > 80))
// do something
```

Comment: aha, what is that dudes name who has the law that you used named after him. i have been trying to remember

Comment: This is an accurate application of De Morgan, but the resulting expression is a bit obfuscated IMO.

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend figuring out how to make it work properly (by rewriting it)

```
if (!((a >= 40 && a <= 50) || (a >= 60 && a <= 80)))
```

should work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "OR"

```
if ((a < 40 || a > 50) && (a < 60 || a > 80))
```

Or, a NOT

```
if (!((a >= 40 && a <= 50) || (a >= 60 && a <= 80)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You second example

```
if ((a < 40 && a > 50) || (a < 60 && a > 80))
```

doesn't make sense as `a` cannot be both less than 40 and greater than 50 (or less than 60 and greater than 80) at the same time.

Something like

```
if (!((a < 40 && a > 50) || (a < 60 && a > 80)))
```

or

```
if ((a < 40 || a > 50) && (a < 60 || a > 80))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the equivalent of

```
if ( not ((a >= 40 && a <= 50) || (a >= 60 && a <= 80)) )
```

then, if you think about the original expression, it should be

```
if (a < 40 || (a > 50 && a < 60) || a > 80)
```

The first expression is allowing **`a`** to be a number from 40 to 50 or from 60 to 80. Negate that in English and you want a number less than 40 or between 50 and 60 or greater than 80.

De Morgan's Laws can get you an accurate answer, but I prefer code that you can read aloud and make sense of.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!((a >= 40 && a <= 50) || (a >= 60 && a <= 80)))
```